# Duplicate Rule is preventing update on possible duplicate record(s) even with Allow setting

Tags: data-loader, flow, duplicate-management

I have a duplicate rule (via Duplicate Management) on account. If an account looks like a duplicate, I have it set to Alert and Report but `Allow` the record to be inserted/updated.

For some reason, however, if an account that looks like a duplicate enters a flow (process) it will throw an error:

> UPDATE --- UPDATE FAILED --- ERRORS : (DUPLICATES_DETECTED) The Dealer
>   you are trying to create appears to be a duplicate. We recommend you
>   use an existing Dealer instead.

I have also seen similar behavior when performing an insert/update/upsert via Data Loader. The record operation will fail with a similar warning.

So it seems that even though I have this rule set to `Allow` a possible duplicate, it is acting like it is blocking it instead.

How can I stop the errors caused by Duplicate Management (without disabling the rule)?

Comment: I am facing this issue with users today too

Comment: did it ever work for you? @swisher

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can set allowSave via flow.  Might have to define an apex class to do inserts and call that class from the builder..

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Database_DMLOptions_DuplicateRuleHeader.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using process builder, so `allowSave` is not an option. I would expect, however, that the `Allow` setting on the rule would take care of this. It appears that something is not working correct. I would understand getting these errors if I had it set to `Block`.

Comment: Know idea/issue:  https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000oLzBAAU

Define an apex class as 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableVariable.htm